# GridLayoutManager spansizelookup not working

Tags: android

I am using a GridLayoutManager so setup the number of columns(per row) of a `recyclerview` dynamically. Here's my code:

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                int num = 0;
                if(position == 0)
                    num = 2;
                else if(position == 1)
                    num = 1;
                else if (position % 4 == 0)
                    num = 1;
                else
                    num = 2;
                Log.i("spansize", "spansize: " + num);
                return num;
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), mBlessingPics, options, ImageAdapter.POPULAR);

        mPopularImagesGrid.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        mPopularImagesGrid.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setOnClick(this);
```

However, it seems that the number of columns is not updated. Please see the picture below:
[image]

I can verify in the logcat that the number of spansize is changing from 2 or 1 but the actual recyclerview doesn't show it. It just shows a single column/span per row.

EDIT:
I could not make the first row have 2 items/columns in them. The second item is always placed in the second row. I intend to have 1 column in the second row to give way for a native ad which will occupy the entire row. I am using this in my spansizelookup:
`return (position % 3) == 0 ? 1 : 2;`
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the important part of your method:

```
if(position == 0)
    num = 2;
else if(position == 1)
    num = 1;
else if (position % 4 == 0)
    num = 1;
else
    num = 2;
```

So the span size will be 1 for positions `1` and `4, 8, 12, 16...` and will be 2 for everything else. This means that there are never two items next to each other with span size 1, and since your grid is only two spans wide, everything needs to be on its own row. I used your `SpanSizeLookup` but with a simple layout and I see this:

[image]

So, if you want to sometimes see two images next to each other and sometimes only see one, you'll need a different algorithm for your span size lookup. For example:

```
return (position % 3) == 0 ? 2 : 1;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just wonder why the first code that you gave didnt worked while `return (position % 3) == 0 ? 2 : 1;` worked? In the first code there is only 1 column. No difference from my code.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo that was my point. I was showing you _why_ the first code doesn't work (which is that you need two items with span size 1 next to each other to get two items in a single row. 1+2 is greater than 2, so everything goes in its own row.

Comment: Thanks again! Please see the edited question. I can't still have the first row to have 2 columns.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo what if you just `return 1` every time, with no logic at all? That should at least tell you whether it's the `SpanSizeLookup` or your layout that's the problem.